# issue with Factory girl - Persist data (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, factory-bot

I have recently started using FactoryGirl instead of Fixtures in my application.
Below is a spec i wrote to test if the data saved using factorygirl appears in a separate page

```
describe "Tasks" do
  describe "GET /Ajax add", :focus do
    it "checks ajax js", :js => true do
      task = FactoryGirl.create(:task, :name => "writing test task")
      visit "/list"
    end
  end
end
```

in the page `/list` i have written code to retrieve all the data in the `tasks` table `(Task model)`.

I can see output when i am running the page by starting server, but when running through the test, it always shows empty page.

Is this because FactoryGirl deletes all the data after use? Or what should I do to persist data even when I visit multiple pages in a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Are you using something like DatabaseCleaner?  Have a look at your test_helper to see if you're doing anything to clean the database

2) Check the return value on task to see that it's actually creating successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues where using Fabricator (FactoryGirl alternative) would not persist to my Capybara sessions. The guys at plataformatec wrote a solution to this. http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/